# MySQL Merging my selects together

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

and thanks for taking the time to try and help me.

### Informations

I'm currently using CodeIgniter if it might have anything to do with your answer ;).

### Problem

I'm in a hotel site, trying to figure out how to do my reservation rooms.

I want users to select a list of available services and return to them, a list of rooms that contains these services ( all of them ) AND after that, a list that contains at least one. This way I'll show to them a list of rooms that comply with all their need, and one that might do the trick, but doesnt have everything.

Here's how I store my services for my rooms ( Here might lie my problem in fact ... )

```
Table "services_rooms"
id_services_rooms | id_room | id_service
1                 | 1       | 1
2                 | 1       | 2
3                 | 1       | 3
5                 | 1       | 5
11                | 2       | 2
12                | 2       | 3
...               | ...     | ...
```

How can I manage to do my SQL to ask my server give me all of the rooms that contains the services 1, 2 AND 3, therefore, only my "id_room" 1 should come back ?

I've tried doing some joins / group_bys but the most I got was for exemple, 3 row coming back saying :

```
Return rows :
ID_ROOM 1 | ID_SERVICE 1
ID_ROOM 1 | ID_SERVICE 2
ID_ROOM 1 | ID_SERVICE 3
```

Another way to see it, would be like that : I want to ask my server which rooms contains ALL of these services : 1,2,3

It would answer : ID_ROOM 1.

I've seen a couple of other questions talking about merges and such but couldn't quite apply their answers to my problem.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called [**Relational Division.**](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

```
SELECT id_room
FROM services_rooms
WHERE id_service IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY id_room
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78256/1)

if unique constraint was not enforced on `id_service` for ech `id_room`, `DISTINCT` is required.

```
SELECT id_room
FROM services_rooms
WHERE id_service IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY id_room
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_service) = 3
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer to your question returns all rooms that have at least one of the services.  The query is:

```
SELECT id_room, count(*) as NumServices
FROM services_rooms
WHERE id_service IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY id_room
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: +1 for returning question asked _list of rooms that contains these services ( all of them ) AND after that, a list that contains at least one._

Comment: Thanks ! Playing with the settings from the other query I was able to figure the same thing as you ( >0 ) :)